# Swift firebase my database got a little complicated how should I access this child?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im using firebase  as my database. So my database got complicated and I got stuck in accessing a specific child.

I have this snippet:

```
for child in snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "rated").children{
             let child = child as! DataSnapshot
```

but after that i don't know what to do .

My json structure looks like this:

```
-LfdhZk3UY9ag5zIYUgh
 rated
  2fLHYArJzCR0wg6waeW23n859pI3
   -Lff-x5TTeOn7ZO1ygDc
     UserId:"05E1OFKYsiWQf2s7LsEm6XM4oWy1"
   -Lff0DsKvs5lnxtFCQL_
     UserId:"Q6jYe9gzAePy8x6SJulTYLMQTpN2"
```

I wanted to access all UserId under 2fLHYArJzCR0wg6waeW23n859pI3. but i'm getting nil all the time and now I'm lost

Comment: Please show your complete call to Firebase. Not easy to find the error with your snippet

Comment: See [Work with Lists of Data on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data).

Comment: You say you got stuck accessing a specific child by you've not told us what child that is so it will be hard to answer. You may need a query but hard to tell, and there may be ways to uncomplicate that structure as well. Need more info.

Comment: As a followup comment, the question content states *I wanted to access all UserId* but the actual question asks *I got stuck in accessing a specific child.*. Which is it - all children in the node (see @frankvanpuffelen) answer or is it a specific child? If it's specific which one and can you show the code you attempted to access that child?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I figured out the problem by using the solution below but I modified it quite a bit:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under `rated` you seem to have two dynamic levels, which you'll typically handle by looping over the children. Then you can access the properties (`UserId`) with `childSnapshot(forPath:)` again.

So something like:

```
for child in snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "rated").children{
    for userSnapshot in child.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
        for dynamicSnapshot in userSnapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let userID = dynamicSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "UserId").value
```